# Decomposition of volume form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M^{2n},\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold. Then $\omega^n$ is a volume form. Suppose that $H \in C^\infty(U)$, where $U \subseteq M$ is open and $dH \neq 0$ on $U$. Why exactly can I decompose
$$\omega^n = dH \wedge \alpha$$
 for a $\alpha \in \Omega^{2n - 1}(U)$? I mean locally I can express both sides in a coordinate induced basis and choose for example a nonzero coefficient of $dH$ in a small neighbourhood.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Hodge star operator?

Comment: @OrEisenberg No, not really. But probably I should get familiar with it. How would it help?

Comment: The Hodge star is essentially defined to provide solutions to the sort of problem you've posed here, so yes. =)

Comment: Why do you think $\alpha$ could be unique? You can obviously add a product of $dH$ with any $(2n-2)$-form.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am sorry. The uniqueness was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed decompose the volume form but the decomposition is definitely not unique. Consider pretty much the simplest example with $n = 1, M = \mathbb{R}^2,\omega = dx \wedge dy$, $U = M$ and $H(x,y) = x$. Then $dH = dx$ and if we take $\alpha = f dx + dy$ where $f$ is any smooth function, we'll get

$$ dH \wedge \alpha = dx \wedge (f dx + dy) = dx \wedge dy = \omega. $$

In general, to show that such a decomposition is possible, write everything down in local coordinates, show that it exists locally and use a partition of unity argument to patch the local solutions to a global one.